# trim video without transcoding on lion

Tags: macos, video, quicktime

On Snow Leopard Quicktime allowed you to easily cut clips from videos and store them as .mov with the trim function (invoked with <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>). On Lion Quicktime, the trim function still exists. But there is no option in the File menu to save the trimmed video as .mov. The only option is to "save for device" which actually trancodes the video (instead of just putting it in a different container) and takes an awful lot of time.

My question is twofold:

1. Will Snow Leopard QuickTime work on Lion? (e.g. if I restore it from backup)
2. Are there any free programs for cutting videos without transcoding?

Comment: Which version(s) of QuickTime are/were you using? I'm assuming that you're using QuickTime Pro to save the mp4 files.

Comment: I am using QuickTime Player Version 10.1 (501.8). I can't recall what old (Snow Leopard) version was. But I'm sure it was still QuickTime Player (not Pro).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure whether Snow Leopard Quick Time will work if you restore it on Lion, since I don't have that version to restore.

However, there are a few freeware utilities that can clip videos:

- According to this [Super User thread](https://superuser.com/questions/250448/how-to-trim-cut-clips-with-vlc), [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-macosx.html) can both cut clips of video without transcoding and also transcode entire streams/files into different formats (see the [VLC wiki](http://wiki.videolan.org/Transcode)).
- How-to Geek has a [guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42107/how-to-quickly-cut-a-clip-from-a-video-file-with-avidemux/) that shows how to quickly cut clips from videos with [Avidemux](http://avidemux.berlios.de/).
- [SimpleMovieX](http://simplemoviex.com/SimpleMovieX/download.html) has a free (unlimited) trial that can also do the trick. The main downside is that the trial version is slower than the paid version.
- [MPEG Streamclip](http://www.squared5.com/) is another freeware tool that provides similar functionality.

One of these utilities may provide the functionality that you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! In summary:
(A) VLC should work but you have to manually enter the start/end time for the new clip.
(B) Precompiled Avidemux crashed. Building it from source would take too long (needs to build QT ui library) and there are no guarantees that it wouldn't crash in the end :-)
(C) SimpleMovieX also worked - saves both to .avi and .mov. The "slow save" comes as 12" pauses during the save process. Not really a problem if you are an occasional user like me.
(D) MPEG Streamclip worked fine - saves to .mov like the good old QT.

Comment: @m000, glad to hear that a few of these worked out for you.